# Getting nested tag item in python

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a automation Script using  selenium, the goal is to scrap indeed jobs. Here is the link to the worldwide url and description of what i need!! .

[indeed worldwide site](https://www.indeed.com/worldwide)

1. what i need is to get all the names of locations and there `hrefs` from the `<a>`,But if found another `<a>` that does not have the wanted results, skip it .
2. save all locations to .json file, something like this :

> ```
> {
> id : '1',title: 'location name', 'href' : 'location href'
> }
> ```

Comment: *from second tag only, and skipping the first tag everytime* - what do u mean by this?

Comment: And what have u tried so far?

Comment: i mean within each <td> element there ,you have two <a> tags, get the name and it's href from second <a>

Comment: What do u want to be there in `title`? Something like Associate Software Engineer?

Comment: sorry, title is key and the value is 'location's name'

Comment: Ok...What is `location href`? The `href` of the job?

Comment: yes exactly .  so i can use the driver to click on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224094/discussion-between-xcoding-and-sushil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/worldwide')

time.sleep(3)

final = {}

a_tags = driver.find_element_by_class_name('countries').find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
idx = 1
for a in a_tags:
    if a.text != "":
        final.setdefault('id',[]).append(idx)
        final.setdefault('title',[]).append(a.text)
        final.setdefault('href',[]).append(a.get_attribute('href'))
        idx += 1
print(final)
driver.close()

with open('D:\\jobs.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(final, f)
```

Output:

```
{'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62], 'title': ['Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Bahrain', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Costa Rica', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Ecuador', 'Egypt', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hong Kong', 'Hungary', 'India', 'Indonesia', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Kuwait', 'Luxembourg', 'Malaysia', 'Mexico', 'Morocco', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Nigeria', 'Norway', 'Oman', 'Pakistan', 'Panama', 'Peru', 'Philippines', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Qatar', 'Romania', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Singapore', 'South Africa', 'South Korea', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Taiwan', 'Thailand', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom', 'Uruguay', 'Venezuela', 'Vietnam'], 'href': ['https://ar.indeed.com/', 'https://au.indeed.com/', 'https://at.indeed.com/', 'https://bh.indeed.com/', 'https://be.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.com.br/', 'https://ca.indeed.com/', 'https://cl.indeed.com/', 'https://cn.indeed.com/', 'https://co.indeed.com/', 'https://cr.indeed.com/', 'https://cz.indeed.com/', 'https://dk.indeed.com/', 'https://ec.indeed.com/', 'https://eg.indeed.com/', 'https://fi.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.fr/', 'https://de.indeed.com/', 'https://gr.indeed.com/', 'https://hk.indeed.com/', 'https://hu.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.co.in/', 'https://id.indeed.com/', 'https://ie.indeed.com/', 'https://il.indeed.com/', 'https://it.indeed.com/', 'https://jp.indeed.com/', 'https://kw.indeed.com/', 'https://lu.indeed.com/', 'https://malaysia.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.com.mx/', 'https://ma.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.nl/', 'https://nz.indeed.com/', 'https://ng.indeed.com/', 'https://no.indeed.com/', 'https://om.indeed.com/', 'https://pk.indeed.com/', 'https://pa.indeed.com/', 'https://pe.indeed.com/', 'https://ph.indeed.com/', 'https://pl.indeed.com/', 'https://pt.indeed.com/', 'https://qa.indeed.com/', 'https://ro.indeed.com/', 'https://ru.indeed.com/', 'https://sa.indeed.com/', 'https://sg.indeed.com/', 'https://za.indeed.com/', 'https://kr.indeed.com/', 'https://es.indeed.com/', 'https://se.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.ch/', 'https://tw.indeed.com/', 'https://th.indeed.com/', 'https://tr.indeed.com/', 'https://ua.indeed.com/', 'https://www.indeed.ae/', 'https://www.indeed.co.uk/', 'https://uy.indeed.com/', 'https://ve.indeed.com/', 'https://vn.indeed.com/']}
```